# PHP NuSoap correct way of sending headers

Tags: php, nusoap

I've been stuck with a HTTP 400 "Bad Request" issue when trying to connect to an API for some time now.

I have a feeling it's to do with the headers, but I'm not too sure.

My query is regarding the output of the SOAP Request and whether I'm correctly setting the headers.

So the code I have to set the header is

```
$proxy->setHeaders('<soap:Header><AuthenticationSoapHeader xmlns="https://www.xxxxx.com/ASPAPI"><Token>xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx</Token></AuthenticationSoapHeader></soap:Header>');
```

I then make a call to an API function and pass over the XML string directly after setting the headers, like so:

```
$result = $proxy->call('ValidateService', array('serviceXML' => $xml));
```

However, the output when printing `$proxy->request` is like so:

```
[TOKEN VALUE FROM HEADER HERE][CONTENTS OF XML STRING HERE]
```

So the `request` string basically prints out the contents of inside the `<token>` tag in the header, directly followed by the XML string.

Is it right that the `<token>` value is printed out in the request alongside the XML string? I have a feeling I may be incorrectly setting the headers.

Answer (score 3):

The problem lies in the headers.

The `<soap:Header>` opening & closing tags were causing the `HTTP Error 400 "Bad Request"`

```
$proxy->setHeaders('<soap:Header><AuthenticationSoapHeader xmlns="https://www.xxxxx.com/aspapi"><Token>xxxxx</Token></AuthenticationSoapHeader></soap:Header>');
```

Should be

```
$proxy->setHeaders('<AuthenticationSoapHeader xmlns="https://www.xxxxx.com/aspapi"><Token>xxxxx</Token></AuthenticationSoapHeader>');
```